# Field 'data_log' doesn't have a default value - Não insere dados no banco

Tags: php, pdo

Não está inserindo dados só usuário no banco, então usei o comando:

```
print_r($inserir->errorInfo());
```

E apareceu este erro:

> Array ( [0] => HY000 [1] => 1364 [2] => Field 'data_log' doesn't have
>   a default value )

No banco existe o data_log, ou seja a data de criação daquele cadastro, não tem nenhuma forma de ignorar este erro e salvar no banco?
Aliás, salvar mas não criar problemas futuros...

```
public function inserir($tabela, $dados){

    $pegarCampos = array_keys($dados);
    $contarCampos = count($pegarCampos);
    $pegarValores = array_values($dados);
    $contarValores = count($pegarValores);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tabela (";

    if($contarCampos == $contarValores){
        foreach($pegarCampos as $campo){
            $sql .= $campo.', ';
        }
        $sql = substr_replace($sql, ")", -2, 1);
        $sql .= "VALUES (";

        for($i = 0; $i < $contarValores; $i++){
            $sql .= "?, ";
            $i;
        }

        $sql = substr_replace($sql, ")", -2, 1);
    }else{
        return false;   
    }

    try{
        $inserir = self::conn()->prepare($sql);
        if($inserir->execute($pegarValores)){
            return true;    
        }else{
            return false;   
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        print_r($inserir->errorInfo());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece devido o mysql-strict que está configurado no seu servidor, desta forma, o campo data_log não pode ficar vazio quando você está inserindo os dados.

Pode desativar o mysql strict desta forma:

```
set @@global.sql_mode='';
```

Ou em sua query, inserir algum valor em data_log